# How to read only first n characters from each line in c language?

Tags: c, stdin

Suppose, I have a file with the following contents

```
abcdefghijkl
mnopqrstuvwx
yz1234567890
```

and I only want to read the first 5 characters from each line so the it can be like the following:

```
abcde
mnopq
yz123
```

I tried the following solution,

```
char line[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        char c = getchar();
        line[i] = c;
        printf("%c", line[i]);
    }
```

but it does not work. How can I solve this?

Comment: It doesn't work how?

Comment: By reading whole lines with `fgets` and truncating them to 5 characters length.

Comment: it reads the whole line and prints out the whole line

Comment: @WeatherVane how?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a demonstrative program. For simplicity instead of an external file there is used the standard input stream `stdin`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char line[6];

    while ( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), stdin ) != NULL )
    {
        char *p = strchr( line, '\n' );

        if ( !p ) fscanf( stdin, "%*[^\n]\n" );
        else *p = '\0';

        puts( line );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
abcdefghijkl 
xyz
mnopqrstuvwx
yz1234567890
```

then the output will be

```
abcde
xyz
mnopq
yz123
```

Comment: How can I do it so it only uses getchar() and putchar()?

Comment: @NeelPatelWhat are you going to use only getchar and putchar when a solution is already provided?

Comment: If you want a solution using only `getchar()`, then look at the other answers. One of them provides exactly what you want. Also, please accept the answer if it solved your problem. But when deciding which answer to accept, also take into account that the restriction on not using `fgets()` was not part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Simple function https://godbolt.org/z/2UP4JW

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char *read5chars(char *buff, FILE *fp)
{
    int ch;
    char *ret;

    ret = fgets(buff, 6, fp);
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
    }while(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF);

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    char line[6];

    while(read5chars(line, stdin))
        printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted will read 5 bytes from stdin and print them. This code should work.

The problem with your code is probably that you are not discarding the remaining characters on the line before reading the next line with the same loop. Since you did not post the code which is calling the loop, I have no way of knowing.